# NSIS ${LineRead} dont give the correct information

Tags: nsis

For an installer i need a specific delete  function.
In case i have a txt-file where i have all Folders where i need to delete.

The txt File is Build up in this way:

> addon1Success 
>   addon2Success 
>   addon3Failed

I have around 10 of this lines.

The main Problem is that when i print out the Information where i get from
the [${LineRead}](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/LineRead) - Function is not the Line like above its a number like in my test case 30. 
Maybe i have a mistake in my code:

```
 !include "${NSISDIR}\Include\LogicLib.nsh"
 !include "myLogger.nsh" ;
 Var i

 Function removeFolder
 IntOp $i $i * 0
  ${ForEach} $i 0 $lineCount + 1
    ${LineRead} "$TEMP\addonInstallerPreFolder\addons\postponeLog.txt" "$i - $i" $0
    !insertmacro LOGGER_WRITE "DEBUG Text $0" "0"

    ${StrContains} $0 "Success" $1
    ${if} $1 == "Success"
        Push "Success"
    ${else}
        Push "Failed"
    ${endif}
    Push $0
    Call Slice
    Pop $R0

    ${if} $revertAfter == "true"
        CopyFiles "$INSTDIR\addons\backup_$R0\*" "$INSTDIR\addons\$R0"
        !insertmacro LOGGER_WRITE "Revert Backupfolder to AddonFolder $R0" "0"
    ${endif}
    !insertmacro LOGGER_WRITE "Removed Backup folder of $R0" "0"
    Delete "$INSTDIR\addons\backup_$R0"
${next}
FunctionEnd
```

i hope you can help to finde the resolve that i get only a digit and not a text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Cris
Looking at your code

```
${LineRead} "$TEMP\addonInstallerPreFolder\addons\postponeLog.txt" "$i - $i" $0
```

First: The third variable "[LineNumber]" should be a single digit. It looks like you have the variable $i - $i. I believe you just need "$i".

Second: The fourth variable in the documentation
[LineRead](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/LineRead) function shows using $R0. It looks like you are using $0 for the function, and using $0 in some areas of your code, but using $R0 in other areas.

Comment: Sry for my late reply i wasnt at work until today. It was like you said i set the false parameters to my function. But i can also use other Variabels like R$1 and so on. Now the critcal Part is working.